# How to use highest() for specific bar periods instead of only the last X bars?

Tags: pine-script

How can we use the highest or lowest (or any other Pine script function) to get results between a specific bar range, instead of getting only from the last X bars.

Lets say you want to compare the highest of the last 10 bars, with the highest between bar -10 and -40?

```
MyCondition = highest(close, [bar -10 to -40) >= highest(close, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a **for loop** between whatever candles arrays you want and store the highest value?

give it a try if you have any find the solution or have doubts pls comment again

Happy codes,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history-referencing operator on function calls:

```
MyCondition = highest(close, 31)[10] >= highest(close, 10)
```